# Ignore an onclick to prevent a JS error

Tags: javascript, null, google-analytics

I used old Google Analytics code and have a bunch of links that had the pageTracker function attached to them so that they counted each click as well.  Well now that I upgraded to newest GA, pageTracker doesn't work anymore, which is OK, but the links show a JS error in IE because pageTracker is undefined.  I don't want to go through all links and remove all pageTracker onclicks, but just want to find a way to nullify those so they don't cause the error.

I've tried var pageTracker = ""; and var pageTracker = null; but still get an undefined error.  This is what a link looks like.

```
<p><a href="/gotowebsite/" onclick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/GoToTheWebsiteLink');">Go to the website</a><br />
```

Here it is in JSFiddle.  When you click the link in IE, you see the JS error for a brief period of time till the next page loads.
http://jsfiddle.net/Fvp9F/

Answer (score 0):

just try to add a fake `pageTracker` object like this (of course it's better do it only if it was not previously defined)

```
if (!pageTracker) { /* if pageTracker is not defined */
    var pageTracker = {
        "_trackPageview" : function() {

        }            
    }
}
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fvp9F/6/

Comment: I still get an error on this one too.  I'm running IE8. Hmm, I wonder what gives.

Answer (score 0):

You were really close, just need to turn it into a blank object:

```
var pageTracker = {_trackPageview: function(){}};
```

Comment: Cool.  For some reason, I still get the JS undefined error though.
http://jsfiddle.net/Fvp9F/5/

Answer (score 0):

Even better than adding a fake/blank pageTracker object, you ought to be able to get the pageTracker from the _gat global and still have old tracking code work.

```
pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
```

One problem is that you need to make sure to get the tracker *after* the async tracking code has been loaded. `_gaq.push()` also allows function objects -- adding the following to your async tracking code ought to work:

```
_gaq.push(function() { pageTracker = _gat._getTracker(); });
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  But I'm using a global way which automatically attaches onclicks to each link so I wouldn't need this.  Good to know though!

Comment: The http://jsfiddle.net/Fvp9F/5/ error is because you've specified onLoad for the javascript, so it get's wrapped in a function, which makes `pageTracker` local to the function. Either get rid of `var` which will force `pageTracker` to be global, and/or change to `no wrap (head)`

Comment: Ahh gotcha.  That makes sense now that you said it. Thanks again!